# Maltego on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

How to install Maltego CE on Ubuntu 14.04 ? I have it installed but it does not load up.
Perhaps ,someone would help me with installation and settings. thanks

Comment: What does "it does not load up" mean? What happens when you try? Do you get any errors? Try running it from the terminal

Answer (score 1):

Maltego does not seem to work with **java 8**. If you have **openjdk 7** installed, you can start maltego with

```
/usr/share/MaltegoTungstenCE/bin/maltego --jdkhome /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/
```

You can also tell maltego to always use this JRE by modifying `/usr/share/MaltegoTungstenCE/etc/maltego.conf`

add the following line

```
jdkhome="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre"
```

Answer (score 1):

update link on new version (work on java jdk 1.8): `sudo apt-get install default-jdk`

`wget -c https://www.paterva.com/malv4/community/MaltegoCE.v4.0.11.9358.deb`

PS at oldest version have problem with certificate chain

Answer (score 0):

You can install `maltego` in Ubuntu 14.04 with [ppa:darklordpaunik8880/darkminttrustytahr](https://launchpad.net/~darklordpaunik8880/+archive/ubuntu/darkminttrustytahr/+index?batch=75&memo=75&start=75)  repository.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:darklordpaunik8880/darkminttrustytahr

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install maltego
```

---

** Other method

Download the `MaltegoCE.v3.4.0.5004.deb` file from [Official site](https://www.paterva.com/web6/products/download4.php)

```
cd ~/Downloads

wget -c https://www.paterva.com/malv34/community/MaltegoCE.v3.4.0.5004.deb

sudo dpkg -i MaltegoCE.v3.4.0.5004.deb
```

Comment: I tried your method but still it does not load up...I tried from the terminal and this is what I get ...sudo maltego
[sudo] password for mtawa: 
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=128m; support was removed in 8.0

Answer (score -1):

Dowload the Maltego file from the Official Site

https://www.paterva.com/malv35/community/MaltegoCarbonCE.v3.5.3.deb

cd /Dowloads

sudo dpkg -i MaltegoCarbonCE.v3.5.3.deb

and that's it